# Android Loading Error: Performing Stop of Activity that is Not Resumed

Tags: java, android, android-activity, firebase

I am creating a loading screen for my application, checking with Firebase to see if the user is logged in. Depending on the authentication state of the user, I will load a specific activity within my application.

I am receiving what appears to be a redundant error that is freezing my application and not accessing the next activity:

```
04-18 21:13:52.400 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -2147483646
04-18 21:13:52.475 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:13:52.475 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:13:52.840 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:53.147 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:53.240 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:13:53.240 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:13:53.653 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:53.972 32330-32330/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3496)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1385)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-18 21:13:54.086 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:54.173 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:13:54.173 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:13:54.783 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:55.063 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:55.144 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:13:55.144 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:13:55.538 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:55.820 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:55.913 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:13:55.914 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:13:56.341 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:56.710 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:56.790 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:13:56.790 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:13:57.260 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:57.527 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:57.612 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:13:57.612 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:13:58.099 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:58.456 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:13:58.637 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:13:58.637 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:13:59.263 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:00.224 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:00.308 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:00.308 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:00.644 32330-32330/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3496)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1385)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-18 21:14:00.694 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:00.895 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:00.895 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:01.378 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -2147483646
04-18 21:14:01.735 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:01.825 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:01.825 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:02.940 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:03.687 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:03.793 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:03.793 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:03.984 32330-32330/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3496)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1385)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-18 21:14:04.166 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:04.307 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:04.307 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:04.677 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:05.072 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:05.165 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:05.165 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:05.561 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -2147483646
04-18 21:14:05.844 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:05.958 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:05.958 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:07.326 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:07.644 32330-32330/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3496)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1385)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-18 21:14:07.654 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -22
04-18 21:14:07.839 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:07.839 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:09.065 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:09.065 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:12.391 32330-32330/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3496)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1385)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-18 21:14:12.502 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 1, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:12.502 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:13.738 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 1, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:13.738 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:16.893 32330-32330/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.troychuinard.fanpolls.PreferencesActivity}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3496)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3593)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1385)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-18 21:14:17.250 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 1, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Bad file descriptor
04-18 21:14:17.251 32330-32512/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -22
04-18 21:14:38.321 5484-5644/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8cc2500
```

Here is my simple loading activity, I am unsure what is producing this error:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    final Firebase userRef = FirebaseUtil.FIREBASE.child("Users");
    final AuthData authData = userRef.getAuth();

    if (authData != null) {
        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String selectedPrefs = (String) dataSnapshot.child(authData.getUid()).child("Selected_Prefs").getValue();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedPrefs) || !selectedPrefs.equals("true")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, PreferencesActivity.class));
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the PreferencesActivity:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    createNavDrawer();
}

private void createNavDrawer() {

    final PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIdentifier(1);
    SecondaryDrawerItem item2 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_previous_polls).withIdentifier(2);
    SecondaryDrawerItem item3 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_preferences).withIdentifier(3);
    SecondaryDrawerItem item4 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_request_poll).withIdentifier(4);
    SecondaryDrawerItem item5 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_suppport).withIdentifier(5);
    SecondaryDrawerItem item6 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_logut).withIdentifier(6);

    AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.ic_facebook)
            .addProfiles(
                    new ProfileDrawerItem().withEmail("bob@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo))
            )
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();


    Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    item1,
                    new DividerDrawerItem(),
                    item2,
                    item3,
                    item4,
                    item5,
                    item6
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    drawerItem.withSetSelected(true);
                    switch ((int)drawerItem.getIdentifier()) {
                        case 1:
                            Intent toHomeActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(toHomeActivity);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Intent toPreferencesActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PreferencesActivity.class);
                            startActivity(toPreferencesActivity);
                            break;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();
         result.setSelection(3);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is your PreferencesActivity?

Comment: I have added the PreferencesActivity, any help is appreciated is I am unable to load my application.

Comment: I guess you are using third party libraries, maybe the errors are related to those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a third-party library to initialize my navigation drawer:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

I have since removed this library and now everything is working perfectly. It looks like Google's recent updates have deprecated this library (either intentionally or unintentionally). My best approach, going forward, would be to always use the native code.

The createNavDrawer() method is where I initialized the library.